# How to enable the second tab after the completion of the first tab validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tab with the following fields

```
 <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
     <b>Name</b>
  <input type="text" id="name"><br/>
  <b>Age</b>
  <input type="text" id="age"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="next" id="submit"/>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
  <form name="nithin">

  </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Tab3</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-4">
    <p>Tab4</p>
  </div>
</div> 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-2" value="2">tabs-2 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-3" value="3">tabs-3 
<input type="checkbox" name="tabs-4" value="4">tabs-4 
<br>
```

Here tab-1 has two fields.The second tab of this must be enable only after the completion of the validation of first tab.We can select show/hide using the checkbox but will not activated.How can I do this? You can see the code [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/52/)

Comment: do you have the validation script or do you need one?

Comment: @Spokey-I didn't included it yet.It contains only empty field checking

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to allow all tabs since the beginning, but to set "disabled" to all the inputs from the others tabs than tab-1. Then when you click on the button from tab-1 (in the callback), select all the inputs from tab-2 and remove their "disabled" attribute? Same for next tabs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example the `input submit` has the class `submit`. I also changed the tab `ids` (see fiddle)

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/2aQ2g/54/

```
$('.submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent from submission and do script instead
    //validation ....
    //if validation is okay, do below
    var nexttab = parseInt($(this).parent().next().attr('id').match(/\d+/g), 10);
    $('#tabs').tabs("enable", nexttab).tabs("select", nexttab);
    $('input[name="tabs-'+nexttab+'"]').removeAttr('disabled').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: @Spokey-But I can take the second tab manualy.How to make it as disable

Comment: The second tab is disabled > `"disabled": [1, 2, 3]`. Not sure I understand what you mean by that.